# polars read_json schema named colums with inferred types

Tags: python, python-polars

The docs for [polars.read_json](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.read_json.html#polars.read_json) say:

> schema : Sequence of str, (str,DataType) pairs, or a {str:DataType,} dict
> The DataFrame schema may be declared in several ways:
>
> - As a dict of {name:type} pairs; if type is None, it will be auto-inferred.
> - As a list of column names; in this case types are automatically inferred.
> - As a list of (name,type) pairs; this is equivalent to the dictionary form.

However I'm unable to use schema with any of the three suggested ways that still rely on automatic type inferrence:

```
import polars as pl
import io
print(pl.__version__)

js = io.StringIO('{"j":null,"k":1,"l":null}')
print(pl.read_json(js))

try:
  print(pl.read_json(js, schema='j k l'.split()))
except Exception as e:
  print(e)

try:
  print(pl.read_json(js, schema={key:None for key in 'j k l'.split()}))
except Exception as e:
  print(e)

try:
  print(pl.read_json(js, schema=[(key, None) for key in 'j k l'.split()]))
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

produces:

```
0.19.9
 k (i64)
 1
shape: (1, 1)
argument 'schema': 'list' object cannot be converted to 'PyDict'
argument 'schema': A NoneType object is not a recognised polars DataType. Hint: use the class without instantiating it.
argument 'schema': 'list' object cannot be converted to 'PyDict'
```

Is there a way to do what I'm after?

Comment: Check this out https://typethepipe.com/vizs-and-tips/python-polars-json-manipulation/

Comment: Thanks @drum - that one seems a bit different since they are explictily specifying the types. I'm trying to only specify the names, which docs imply is supported, then have polars infert the types. Am I missing something from the link you provided?

Comment: It looks like 2 separate "bugs" - a) the dropping of j/l and b) the documented behaviour for `schema` not being implemented.

Comment: I think the issue is `filter_map_nulls` e.g. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/89cc1e2d67448183aa622e1b5f7130793b29b081/crates/polars-json/src/json/infer_schema.rs#L83 - if nulls are filtered, it means any "key" that only has null values is silently dropped.

Comment: The null issue has been fixed in `0.19.16` https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/12677